# What indexing tokenizer should be used for a Array field using elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have a `keyword` field of type `Array` that is generated on the creation of object. What tokenizer should I use for indexing? I couldn't find the information on elasticsearch.org.

keyword value (array):
`['george', 'apple', 'eats', 'new', 'york']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your data and what you want to with it. For example, can a keyword be composed of multiple words? If so, do you want a single word to match or not while searching? Also, do you want it to be case-sensitive or not?

If you want to have only exact matches, case-sensitive, you don't even need to analyze the field and you can configure it as `index: not_analyzed` in your mapping.

If you don't want it to be case-sensitive you can analyze it and use the [keyword tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/keyword-tokenizer.html) which does no tokenization and the [lowercase token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/lowercase-tokenfilter.html).

If a keyword can be composed of more than one words and you want every single word to match you need to tokenize it, for example using the [whitespace tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/whitespace-tokenizer.html) or even the default [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer.html).